# How to deploy sinatra application on myown private server?

Tags: ruby, deployment, sinatra

i am new to sinatra application. i developed my first application with sinatra. Now, i want to deploy this application on my own private server. My own private server is Linux server and all required config (i.e., ruby, sinatra, passenger ) installed.

So, i would like to know how to deploy it?

Comment: i put the code on github, and i pull it to my private server... and then i tried to run "cap production deply":

i got following error: 

The deploy has failed with an error: Exception while executing as root@MYIP: passenger-config exit status: 1
passenger-config stdout: Nothing written
passenger-config stderr: *** ERROR: Phusion Passenger doesn't seem to be running. If you are sure that it
is running, then the causes of this problem could be one of:

Comment: configure your machine to accept connections/requests from others via a port. and map the requests coming via this port to your sinatra app. 
then start your application (this may be `ruby yourapp.rb`, or `shotgun yourapp.rb` or whatever).

Comment: if i run using "ruby app.rb" on terminal, then everytime i should run this...but i want this run automatically...How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Here's our company's basic setup for Ruby microservices APIs:

1) Put your Ruby apps in a special folder

We like /srv/applications/

2) Choose a port for your application

Don't use the default port.  I prefer ones in the 2000 series (E.g., 2000, 2010, 2020, ...) for Ruby apps.

3) Setup a reverse proxy to access your application on that port

Depending on your server, there are lots of Tutorials for [Apache](http://www.apachetutor.org/admin/reverseproxies) or Nginx.

That way /user-api will redirect to your port.  Ex.  myserver.com/user-api goes to myserver.com:2020

4) Run your application

If you're not using bundler, use bundle to run the app.  To run on a specific port, use "bundle exec rackup -p "

You should then be able to access the application.  If you run into trouble, some common problems include 1) the port is being blocked to the outside world, 2) you tried to access it before the app was running and now you still get 503s even though the app is running (restart your webserver to fix it).

Bonus - running your app as a Unix service

This has enormous benefits.  If you can run the Ruby app with another supervisor level app, then you can automatically start it on reboot, automatically restart the app on failures (which can lead to flapping when you have catastrophic problems).

Originally we used [Monit](https://mmonit.com/monit/) which is typically used for service monitoring but can actually start/stop/restart (start on boot) for a service.

Now we use [foreman](http://blog.daviddollar.org/2011/05/06/introducing-foreman.html) and [upstart](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/).  I highly recommend this pairing, as app supervision is the textbook use case for Upstart.  You can skip using Foreman if you have a vanilla configuration, but it is incredibly useful if you need to start other services, set environment variables, etc.